# Remove/add object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I'm having difficulties to perform a simple task and I can't figure it out, I would love if someone can assist.

I have an object with multiple properties and I want to filter out a few of the properties.
I've created an array with the properties that I want to filter out from the object.

```
const str = `
{"id":63,"parent_id":0,"number":"63","order_key":"wc_order_JQR7ZXgFWE4MU","created_via":"admin","version":"3.9.1","status":"pending","currency":"GBP","date_created":"2020-01-30T14:07:52","date_created_gmt":"2020-01-30T14:07:52","date_modified":"2020-01-30T14:08:04","date_modified_gmt":"2020-01-30T14:08:04","discount_total":"0.00","discount_tax":"0.00","shipping_total":"0.00","shipping_tax":"0.00","cart_tax":"0.00","total":"0.00","total_tax":"0.00","prices_include_tax":false,"customer_id":0,"customer_ip_address":"","customer_user_agent":"","customer_note":"","billing":{"first_name":"asfaf","last_name":"asfaf","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":"GB","email":"asasfasf@eta.com","phone":"14124"},"shipping":{"first_name":"","last_name":"","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":""},"payment_method":"","payment_method_title":"","transaction_id":"","date_paid":null,"date_paid_gmt":null,"date_completed":null,"date_completed_gmt":null,"cart_hash":"","meta_data":[],"line_items":[],"tax_lines":[],"shipping_lines":[],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/orders\/63"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/orders"}]}}
`;

const unwanted = ['id', 'parent_id', 'number', 'order_key', 'created_via', 'version', '_links'];
const hey = JSON.parse(str);
```

So I want to return an object without the 'unwanted' properties.

I'm also trying to add a new parameter inside an array that inside this object.
I want to be able to insert this parameter inside the line items array: { product_id: 123 }.
so the line items should look like this:

```
line_items: [
  {
    product_id: 123
  }
]
```

Thanks!

** EDIT **
I found out I can use the delete method.
unwanted.forEach(i => delete hey[i]);

Now I'm trying to figure out how can I add an object into an array inside this object. thanks!

Comment: Please post what you have written to try an accomplish this, and what *specific* problems you are having with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()`;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
const str = `
{"id":63,"parent_id":0,"number":"63","order_key":"wc_order_JQR7ZXgFWE4MU","created_via":"admin","version":"3.9.1","status":"pending","currency":"GBP","date_created":"2020-01-30T14:07:52","date_created_gmt":"2020-01-30T14:07:52","date_modified":"2020-01-30T14:08:04","date_modified_gmt":"2020-01-30T14:08:04","discount_total":"0.00","discount_tax":"0.00","shipping_total":"0.00","shipping_tax":"0.00","cart_tax":"0.00","total":"0.00","total_tax":"0.00","prices_include_tax":false,"customer_id":0,"customer_ip_address":"","customer_user_agent":"","customer_note":"","billing":{"first_name":"asfaf","last_name":"asfaf","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":"GB","email":"asasfasf@eta.com","phone":"14124"},"shipping":{"first_name":"","last_name":"","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":""},"payment_method":"","payment_method_title":"","transaction_id":"","date_paid":null,"date_paid_gmt":null,"date_completed":null,"date_completed_gmt":null,"cart_hash":"","meta_data":[],"line_items":[],"tax_lines":[],"shipping_lines":[],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/orders\/63"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/orders"}]}}
`;

const unwanted = ['id', 'parent_id', 'number', 'order_key', 'created_via', 'version', '_links'];

const obj = JSON.parse(str);


const output = Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, key) => {
   if (unwanted.indexOf(key) > -1 ) {
     prev[key] = obj[key];
   }
   return prev;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found out how to achieve what I want :)
Here are my findings:

```
// remove
unwanted.forEach(i => delete hey[i]);

// add
hey.line_items.push({ product_id: 123 });
```